# Recharts - How to add a round corner to Area Component of type "step"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I have started using [Recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/) and I am struggling with a design issue.

I'm trying to add a border-radius to my Area component that is of type="step".

This is what I currently have : 
[image]

And this is what I am trying to get :

(As you can see, the corners are slightly rounded)
[image]

Does any one know if it is possible to achieve something like that ? If not is their any workaround ?